# Извлечение константы из Enum по ее текстовому значению

Tags: c#, generics, enum

Имеется следующий метод, который возвращает именованную константу из `enum` по ее строковому представлению, либо возвращает значение по-умолчанию в случае неудачи:

```
static TEnum GetEnum<TEnum>(string key, TEnum defaultValue = default(TEnum), bool ignoreCase = true) 
where TEnum : struct, IConvertible {
    TEnum result;
    return Enum.TryParse<TEnum>(key, ignoreCase, out result) ? result : defaultValue;
}
```

Вопрос: почему в нижеприведенном коде для несуществующей константы возвращается некорректный результат? Как это исправить?

```
enum Nums { none = 0, one, two, three, four, five }

Nums res;

res = GetEnum<Nums>("one");
Console.WriteLine($"{res} : {res == Nums.one}");   // one : True
res = GetEnum<Nums>("six");
Console.WriteLine($"{res} : {res == Nums.none}");  // none : True
res = GetEnum<Nums>("123");
Console.WriteLine($"{res} : {res == Nums.none}");  // 123 : False ???
```

Предполагаю, что так происходит из-за числовой интерпретации строки `123`, но всё равно не понятно почему так происходит и как это исправить?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Это странное поведение прописано в [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499(v=vs.110).aspx) :-\

> If `value` is a name that does not correspond to a named constant of `TEnum`, the method returns `false`. If `value` is the string representation of an integer that does not represent an underlying value of the `TEnum` enumeration, the method returns an enumeration member whose underlying value is value converted to an integral type. If this behavior is undesirable, call the [`IsDefined`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined(v=vs.110).aspx) method to ensure that a particular string representation of an integer is actually a member of `TEnum`.

Судя по всему, вам нужно переписать функцию в таком виде:

```
static TEnum GetEnum<TEnum>(
    string key,
    TEnum defaultValue = default(TEnum),
    bool ignoreCase = true)
        where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
{
    TEnum result;
    var b = Enum.TryParse<TEnum>(key, ignoreCase, out result) &&
              Enum.IsDefined(typeof(TEnum), result);
    return b ? result : defaultValue;
}
```

---

Обновление: Модифицированная функция не проходит тест со строками `"1"` и `"one,one"`. Так что, судя по всему, нужно больше проверок:

```
static TEnum GetEnum<TEnum>(
    string key,
    TEnum defaultValue = default(TEnum),
    bool ignoreCase = true)
        where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
{
    TEnum result;
    var b =
        Enum.TryParse<TEnum>(key, ignoreCase, out result) &&
        Enum.IsDefined(typeof(TEnum), result) &&
        string.Equals(result.ToString(), key, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    return b ? result : defaultValue;
}
```

---

Обновление: Код, приведённый выше, не справляется с `GetEnum<System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon>("Error")`, из-за того, что константы в `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon` повторяются! В качестве решения, мы можем опросить список всех имён, и сравнить. Финальный вариант:

```
static TEnum GetEnum<TEnum>(
    string key,
    TEnum defaultValue = default(TEnum),
    bool ignoreCase = true)
        where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
{
    TEnum result;
    if (Enum.GetNames(typeof(TEnum))
            .Contains(key, ignoreCase ? StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase :
                                        StringComparer.Ordinal) &&
        Enum.TryParse<TEnum>(key, ignoreCase, out result))
        return result;
    else       
        return defaultValue;
}
```

[Можно было бы обойтись проверкой `Enum.IsDefined(typeof(TEnum), key)` (не `result`!), но в ней невозможно запросить игнорирование регистра.]

---

Обновление: По результатам дискуссии в комментариях, можно воспользоваться менее красивым, но более эффективным кодом:

```
static TEnum GetEnum<TEnum>(
    string key,
    TEnum defaultValue = default(TEnum),
    bool ignoreCase = true)
        where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
{
    var comparisonType = ignoreCase ? StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase :
                                      StringComparison.Ordinal;
    var names = Enum.GetNames(typeof(TEnum));
    foreach (var name in names)
    {
        if (name.Equals(key, comparisonType))
            return (TEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(TEnum), key, ignoreCase);
    }
    return defaultValue;
}
```

Его суть та же, просто некоторые операции «расписаны». Бенчмарк в комментариях.

---

Если вам нужна экстремальная микрооптимизация, и вы **понимаете** проблемы с кешированием, вот вам ещё более быстрый кэширующий вариант, котрый придумал @Pavel Mayorov:

```
private class Holder<TEnum>
{
    // относительный порядок элементов в массивах гарантирован документацией
    public static readonly TEnum[] values = (TEnum[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum));
    public static readonly string[] names = Enum.GetNames(typeof(TEnum));
}

static TEnum GetEnum<TEnum>(
    string key,
    TEnum defaultValue = default(TEnum),
    bool ignoreCase = true)
        where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
{
    var comparisonType = ignoreCase ? StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase :
                                      StringComparison.Ordinal;
    for (int i = 0; i < Holder<TEnum>.names.Length; i++)
    {
        if (Holder<TEnum>.names[i].Equals(key, comparisonType))
            return Holder<TEnum>.values[i];
    }
    return defaultValue;
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51934/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd----enum----).

Answer (score 5):

Это происходит потому, что [внутри](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/bdb5b3bd2fb82fff.html) `TryParse` есть две ветки:

- Если переданная строка оказалась действительно строковым значением (не числом), то метод честно сравнивает его со всем именами членов, определенным в енаме.
- Если переданная строка оказалась числом, то метод возвращает значение енама, значение которого совпадает с указанным числом. Однако если в енаме нет члена с таким значением, то возвращается *само это число*.

Поэтому если вам нужно парсить енам из строки, при этом в строке могут быть как названия членов енама, так и их значения, то нужно дополнительно использовать метод `IsDefined()`.

Answer (score -1):

Это происходит из-за того, что во множестве нет числа 123, а раз 123 не равно 0 то и результат False. Попробуйте вместо 123 указать 0, тогда результат будет True.

Comment: вы не поняли вопроса.