# Enum. Как определить, что значение перечисления не определено?

Tags: c#

Как определить, что значение перечисления не определено? К примеру ,результат = 3

```
public enum ResultCode
{
  Success,
  Error
}
```

Comment: [IsDefined](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.enum.isdefined(v=vs.110).aspx) и вроде бы тут был хороший ответ на эту тему

Comment: Не совсем то же самое, но ответ хороший: [Извлечение константы из Enum по ее текстовому значению](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/572094/186999)

Comment: То, что надо. Спасибо

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для определения того, что значение перечисления входит в список констант с указанными значениями применяется метод [IsDefined](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.enum.isdefined(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public ResultCode PerformAction()
{
  int result = ResultCodeFromDataSource();

   if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(ResultCode), result))
   {
      throw new InvalidOperationException("Дружище, выход за диапазон");
   }

   return (ResultCode) result;
}
```

Справочная информация: [enum (Справочник по C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/sbbt4032.aspx)

Comment: и ссылку на msdn с пояснением добавь в ответ

Comment: Добавил то, что было.

Comment: Я уже подредактировал :)

Comment: ) спасибо. На самом деле получилось неплохо.