# C#. Работа с параметрами

Tags: c#, winforms

Параметру передаю таким образом значение:

```
Properties.Settings.Default["Имя параметра"] = value;
```

Вопрос в следующем. Как определить, что тип устанавливаемого значения соответствует типу параметра? Как привести значение `value` к типу параметра?

```
 public void SetProperty(string nameProperty, string valueProperty)
        {
         ErrorManipulation(null, enumResultCode.Success);//Устанавливаем значения по умолчанию

        //Сохраняем параметр
        //string nameProperty = value; //Наименование параметра
        Type typeProperty = Properties.Settings.Default[nameProperty].GetType(); //Тип значения параметра

        try
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default[nameProperty] = Convert.ChangeType(valueProperty, typeProperty);  //передаваемое значение приводим к типу параметра
            PropportiesSave(); //сохраняем значение параметра
        }
        catch (Exception e) //Если не удалось преобразовать значение
        {
            ErrorManipulation(string.Format("{0}; Источник: {1}", e.Message, e.Source), enumResultCode.Error);//Устанавливаем значения при возникновении исключения
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы привести `Value` к типу параметра:

```
Properties.Settings.Default["Имя параметра"] = Convert.ChangeType(Value, Properties.Settings.Default["Имя параметра"].GetType());  
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Comment: А можете отредактировать ответ, чтобы в случае правки вопроса он остался действительным? Что-то вроде "Для того, чтобы привести значение value к типу параметра...".

Comment: Это не сработает, если `Properties.Settings.Default["Имя параметра"]` равно `null`.

Answer (score 3):

Более прямой метод — использовать готовые типизированные свойства.

Когда вы создаёте значение параметра с именем `MyParameter` какого-нибудь типа, у вас создаётся свойство с тем же именем и тем же типом. Поэтому проще всего работать через свойство: код

```
Properties.Settings.Default.MyParameter = value;
```

просто не скомпилируется, если тип `value` неверен.

---

Если имя параметра неизвестно во время компиляции, тут немного сложнее. Для начала, задумайтесь, правильную ли вы выбрали задачу: зачем вам свойство с неизвестным именем? Может быть, вам нужен просто `Dictionary`?

Если всё же вам нужны именно `Settings`, вы можете получить тип по имени, используя конструкцию

```
Type propertyType = Properties.Settings.Default.Properties["TestSetting"].PropertyType;
```

Имея тип, можно проверить, возможно ли присваивание:

```
if (propertyType.IsAssignableFrom(value.GetType()))
{
    ...
```

---

**Обновление:**

Если целевой тип — `enum`, а исходное значение представлено в виде строки, то лучше всего делать так.

```
enum Colors
{
    Red, Green, Blue, Yellow, Error
}
```

```
Colors color;
if (!Enum.TryParse<Colors>(value, out color))
{
    color = Colors.Error;
    // вывести сообщение об ошибке
}

Properties.Settings.Default.MyParameter = color;
```

Немного более продвинутый вариант рассматривается [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/572094/10105).

Comment: А если Value ="123", работать тоже не будет.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов: Зависит от типа параметра в Settings.

Comment: Допустим, тип Int. В данном примере строка не будет преобразована в число.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов: Ну да. Но это ж хорошо? Или вам нужно в этом случае тоже попытаться сконвертировать? А что если в строке не число, что тогда должно произойти?

Comment: Это уже отдельная обработка подаваемого значения

Comment: ИМЯ ПАРАМЕТРА ИЗВЕСТНО.

Comment: Да, всегда нужно конвертировать.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов: А что должно произойти, если конверсия не проходит? Например, если пришла строка с буквами?

Comment: Использую enum. В этом случае будет установлено значение Error. Должно быть выведено сообщение с содержанием исключения.

Comment: В ответе, в котором я написал это не предусмотрено. В твоем ответе идет проверка на соответствие типу Value. А мне нужно value привести к типу параметра. Очень нужна помощь, никак не могу сделать.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов: Обновил ответ

Comment: Может я не корректно объясняю. Перечисление я использую для того, чтобы знать как отработал метод. Если возникло исключение, то возвращаю Error и передаю строку содержащую текст ошибки. Суть в том, что в таблице заполняются значения параметров. Далее их сохраняю.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов: Покажите лучше пример кода, может, будет понятнее.