# Как узнать, что невозможно преобразовать int в enum?

Tags: c#, cast

Дано:

```
enum LANGUAGES{
    EN,
    RU,
    FR
}
int res = 7;
```

Как узнать правильно, что (LANGUAGES)res выдаст неверный результат (результат не принадлежит LANGUAGES)?

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Извлечение константы из Enum по ее текстовому значению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/572077/186999)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Используйте Enum.IsDefined как указано в документации ([раз](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.enum.isdefined?view=netframework-4.7.2), [два](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.enum.parse?view=netcore-2.0)).

```
if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(LANGUAGES), res))
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is into language enumeration.", res);
else
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is not into language enumeration.", res);
```