# Как работает алгоритм определения Enum-значения в C#?

Tags: c#

Как работает алгоритм определения enum-значения в C# в примере?

Основной код:

```
void Main()
{
    Numbers number;
    number = Numbers.Four;

    Console.WriteLine((int) number);
    Console.WriteLine(number);
    Console.WriteLine(Numbers.Four);
}
```

---

**Пример 1:**

```
enum Numbers {
    One,
    Two,
    Three,
    Four = 1,
    Five,
    Six
}
```

Задаем значение 1 для Four

В результате выполнения получается:

> 1   Four   Four

Если декомпилировать, то можно увидеть следующее:

```
private enum Numbers
{
    One = 0,
    Two = 1,
    Three = 2,
    Four = 1,
    Five = 2,
    Six = 3
}
```

---

**Пример 2**

```
 enum Numbers {
    One,
    Two,
    Three,
    Four = 2,
    Five,
    Six
 }
```

Задаем значение 2 для Four

В результате выполнения получается:

> 2 Three Three

После декомпиляции получается следующее:

```
private enum Numbers
{
    One = 0,
    Two = 1,
    Three = 2,
    Four = 2,
    Five = 3,
    Six = 4
}
```

---

**Почему в первом примере выбирается последнее соответствующее значение, а во втором примере выбирается первое соответствующее значение ?**

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37263124/7145756

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если явно не присваивать значения, то они будут проинициализированы значениями начиная с нуля и далее.

```cs
// все значения генерируются по умолчанию
enum Numbers
{
    Zero, // 0
    One, // 1
    Two, // 2
    Three // 3
}
enum Numbers
{
    Zero, // 0
    One, // 1
    Two = 1, // 1, "нумерация" началась заново
    Three // 2, это и последующие значения +1
}
enum Numbers
{
    Zero, // 0
    One, // 1
    Two = 1,
    Three, // 2
    Four, // 3
    Five = 2,
    Six // 3
}
```

За кулисами enum - это struct с константами:

```cs
enum Numbers
{
  Zero,
  One,
  Two
}
// struct Numbers : System.Enum
// {
//     public const int Zero = 0;
//     public const int One = 1;
//     public const int Two = 2;
// }
```

Могу ошибаться, но мне кажется, что при наличии не уникальных значений в enum порядок их возврата не гарантирован, а использовать такой подход нужно только там, где это действительно необходимо. Например, [MessageBoxIcon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messageboxicon?view=netframework-4.8) имеeт одинаковые значения (скорее всего для обратной совместимости) и в этом нет ([практически](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/572077/182750)) ничего страшного. Но если взять Ваш пример, то получается, что `Numbers.Two == Numbers.Four`, что не соответствует семантике.
Лучше всегда явно указывать значения перечисления.

Comment: Почитайте, пожалуйста, вопрос. То, что нумерация начинается, видно в результатах декомпиляции.

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk поправил ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Нашел ответ на SO.

Ссылка ответа на вопрос: [Which Enum constant will I get if the Enum values are same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37263227/7145756)

В [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tostring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Enum_ToString_System_String_) (Notes to Callers) сказано:

> Если несколько членов перечисления имеют одинаковое базовое значение,
>   и вы пытаетесь получить строковое представление имени члена
>   перечисления на основе его базового значения, то ваш код не должен
>   делать никаких предположений о том, какое имя метод возвратит.

Так же, из ответа на SO

> Однако это не значит, что результат случайный. Это означает, что это
>   деталь реализации, которая может быть изменена. Реализация может
>   полностью измениться с помощью всего лишь патча, может отличаться в
>   разных компиляторах (MONO, Roslyn и т. Д.) И быть разной на разных
>   платформах.
>
> Если ваша система спроектирована так, что требует, чтобы обратный
>   поиск перечислений был согласован по времени и платформам, тогда не
>   используйте `Enum.ToString`. Либо измените свой дизайн, чтобы он не
>   зависел от этих деталей, либо напишите свой собственный метод, который
>   будет согласован.
>
> Поэтому вам не следует писать код, который зависит от этой реализации,
>   иначе вы рискует, что он изменится без вашего ведома в будущем.

Comment: Рекомендую посмотреть данный [пример](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V6aBYgcNnlg&t=307s)

Comment: Т.е. я был прав: "... при наличии не уникальных значений в enum порядок их возврата не гарантирован".